# How do I kick off a Runnable RabbitMQ listener when my play framework scala application starts?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, background-process, actor

So I have a RESTful play app that interacts (or is going to interact very soon) with a couple of other micro-restful-services.

However I need to start my Runnable RabbitMQ class shortly after play startup so that I can trigger some akka actors to do stuff.

So far I've got the application responding to "GET" routes / /status and all is good, but I keep getting linked to "Scheduled Tasks" as a way to do a background job in Play. Is that the right way to do so?

`system.scheduler().scheduleOnce()` ??

As suggested here: [Running a continuous background task in Play 2.4.2 server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327907/running-a-continuous-background-task-in-play-2-4-2-server)

---

Edit: Trying what Lief Ericson suggested but get an error:

```
//@Singleton  Get the error below when I uncomment this <<-----
class Test extends Runnable {

  val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass.getName)

  def run() = {
    while(true) {
      logger.info("I'm here #################")
      Thread.sleep(10000)
    }
  }
}

class Bindings extends AbstractModule {

  val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass.getName)

  override def configure() = {
    logger.info("Configuring application ....")
    bind(classOf[Test]).asEagerSingleton()
  }
}
```

Error:

```
[error] C:\PROJECTS\active\voldemort\app\controllers\Application.scala:29: trait Singleton is abstract; cannot be instantiated
[error] @Singleton
[error]  ^
```

But when i comment out the singleton decorator, I get the log message `"Configuring application ..."` just fine but not `I'm here #########` log line

Comment: Another alternative: should I extend GlobalSettings and do it that way?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a class, say `RabbitListener`, and start that listener in the class constructor:

```
@Singleton
class RabbitListener(listener: Listener[T]) {
    listener.run()
     ...
}
```

Then, you need to make that class eagerly load using Guice `Module`:

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
class Bindings extends AbstractModule {
  override def configure() = {
    bind(classOf[RabbitListener]).asEagerSingleton()
  }
}
```

Then, you need to register the module in `application.conf`:

```
play.modules.enabled += org.example.Bindings
```

Some reference here:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/GlobalSettings#scala

Comment: I was just reading couple of pages on DI and Module, and certainly have read the page you linked (probably several times) but how did you find this from that page? I searched for AbstractModule or play.modules.enabled on that page and got zero hits? Play documentation is still lacking for n00bs who need a little more hand-holding. But I'll try above...

Comment: The link is just some reference, I knew it wasn't the whole explanation, but thought it might help. The docs are a bit of scattered but overall they are fine

Comment: Which package is AbstractModule in? play.api?

Comment: I get a `trait Singleton is abstract; cannot be instantiated` on my Test Runnable. I'll edit my question with my test code

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, here's the ugly solution (which i know isn't the right way of doing things, so hopefully someone can respond) but it works and does what I need it to (which is listen for Rest Calls but also run an RMQ background listener)

```
case object StartConsumingMessage

class RabbitMQConsumer {
  val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass.getName)
  logger.info("Voldemort Actor System starting...")
  val system = ActorSystem("VoldemortSystem")
  val actor = system.actorOf(Props(new RMQConsumerActor()))
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(300 seconds)
  actor ! StartConsumingMessage

}

class Bindings extends AbstractModule {

  val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass.getName)

  override def configure() = {
    logger.info("Configuring application ....")
    bind(classOf[RabbitMQConsumer]).asEagerSingleton()
  }
}
```